# Sparse svd in Armadillo (C++)

Tags: c++, armadillo, svd, eigenvalue

According to, http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#part_c , Armadillo has support for following functions:

```
eig_sym
eig_gen
eigs_sym
eigs_gen
svd
svd_econ
```

But there does not seem to be a function like "svds_econ", which operates on "sparse" matrix and returns singular values and vectors.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality in Armadillo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sparse SVD can be computed indirectly. For example, first calculate *X'*X* or *X*X'*, and then pass the resultant matrix to eigs_sym(). Another way is to first construct a sparse matrix like *[zeros(m,m) X; X' zeros(n,n)]*, where *m* and *n* indicate the number of rows and columns in *X*.

You may also want to scale *X* by its 1-norm beforehand, to increase stability.

Comment: Thanks! For me, X matrix is too large to compute X'*X or X*X'. So 
[0 X; X' 0] seems like a better option. But I don't follow how to get svd from eig on that matrix. Any hints or references?

Comment: Have a look at the source for _svds()_ in [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/).  This can be done by loading Octave and doing `type svds.m`.  Essentially _svds()_ takes the output from _eigs()_ and manipulates the eigenvectors stored in `V`, like so: `u = root2 * V(1:m,ind); ... v = root2 * V(m+1:end,ind);`

Answer (score 5):

As of version 5.0, Armadillo has the [svds()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#svds) function for obtaining a limited number of singular values and singular vectors.